# Adding to BlockingCollection after CompleteAdding is called

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm using a Producer-Consumer pattern and I use a `BlockingCollection` that produces data and consumes data from it. I call a method to produce the data and then set the `BlockingCollection` to `CompleteAdding` so that the consumer consumes all the data from the `BlockingCollection`. After some processing the application wants to add some other data to the `BlockingCollection`, but it can't because it is set to `CompleteAdding`, how can I set `CompleteAdding` to false, or how can I consume all the data from the `BlockingCollection`, not waiting for the `ComleteAdding`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't - the whole point of calling `CompleteAdding` is to say, "There will never be any more data added to this collection. Once it's empty, you know you're done." What you're asking for is a bit like saying, "After I've closed a network connection, how can I reopen it so I can write more data?"

The fact that you *want* to suggests you should rethink your design. Perhaps you should be creating a new `BlockingCollection` at this point instead? Or perhaps you don't *really* want to call `CompleteAdding` to start with?

Comment: But if I don't call CompleteAdding, how does the loop ends ? because i use a loop wiht .GetConsumingEnumerable() property

Comment: @XandrUu: It doesn't, in general - which would be right, because you'd be putting more data in. If you want a "finished this batch" idea, you might want to consider a sentinel value... or have a collection per batch.

Comment: @JonSkeet what would be the usecase for calling it, ie: why would you limit yourself to saying, this collection is closed?

Comment: @KoMet: So that anything which needs to know that it's completed (e.g. to commit a DB transaction) knows that all the work is done. It's *very* useful to know when you've finished.

Comment: @JonSkeet thx, was looking at this in a whole other light, consumer/producer in mvvm applic.

Comment: Sounds like it would be useful for batch processing. Not so much as a processing pipeline buffer.

Comment: Well, it is useful in any situation you want to shutdown resources gracefully. Imagine you are reading from the queue in a separate thread, the queue is empty (or not) and you want to shutdown the thread. Then you simply call the CompleteAdding method, the foreach exits, and the thread goes down.